# what does the $ld$add$os10.4$ prefix mean when I use nm to look at a symbol list on a Mac?

Tags: ios, symbols, undefined-symbol, nm

I'm having some problems with my iPhone app not linking for the iPhone Simulator. It tells me there are undefined symbols:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  ".objc_class_name_NSRunLoop", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSDate", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libRenderSystem_GLES2Static.a(OgreEAGL2Window.mm.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.mm.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_AppDelegate in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
  ".objc_class_name_UIView", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_SampleBrowserGestureView in SampleBrowser.cpp.o
      .objc_class_name_InputDelegate in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.mm.o)
      .objc_class_name_EAGL2View in libRenderSystem_GLES2Static.a(OgreEAGL2View.mm.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIScreen", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.mm.o)
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libRenderSystem_GLES2Static.a(OgreEAGL2Support.mm.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIAccelerometer", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.mm.o)
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOIS.a(iPhoneAccelerometer.mm.o)
```

But these looks like the names of Objective-C classes from frameworks which I *AM* linking against. I wanted to do some digging around so I used nm to look at the symbol list of the frameworks I'm linking against. For instance

```
josh$ nm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation -arch i386 -g | grep objc_class
001a4500 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSArray
001a4501 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSCalendar
001a4502 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSData
001a4503 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSDate
001a4504 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSDateComponents
001a4505 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSDictionary
001a4506 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSEnumerator
001a4507 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSException
001a4508 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSInputStream
001a4509 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSInvocation
001a450a S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSLocale
001a450b S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSMethodSignature
001a450c S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSMutableArray
001a450d S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSMutableData
001a450e S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSMutableDictionary
001a450f S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSMutableSet
001a4510 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSNull
001a4511 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSObject
001a4512 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSOutputStream
001a4513 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSRunLoop
001a4514 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSSet
001a4515 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSStream
001a4516 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSTimeZone
001a4517 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSTimer
001a4548 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSURL
001a4518 S $ld$add$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSUserDefaults
001a4549 S $ld$add$os10.5$.objc_class_name_NSURL
001a454a S $ld$hide$os10.4$.objc_class_name_NSFileWrapper
001a454b S $ld$hide$os10.5$.objc_class_name_NSFileWrapper
001a454c S $ld$hide$os10.6$.objc_class_name_NSFileWrapper
```

Now, this symbol list makes it look to me like that framework archive IS exporting the classes that the linker is looking for. The only thing that's different is this $ld$add$os10.4$ prefix. I'm wondering why it's there, what it means, and is that, perhaps, causing my problem?

Edit:
Looks like this was my problem: 
[Link errors in Xcode when targeting iPhoneSimulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010175/link-errors-in-xcode-when-targeting-iphonesimulator)

In short, leaving off the compiler flag -fobjc-abi-version=2 leads to the different symbol naming.

Comment: My guess is that os10.4 stands for "OS X" ("X" is the Roman numeral "ten").

Comment: I figure the same as far as the numbering, but why are only some symbols prefixed this way (i.e. not _NSRunLoopCommonModes, _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRunLoop, etc), and more importantly, why is the linker looking for unprefixed symbols?

Comment: I found where apple is printing out those symbols.  See [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-318.0.45/src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/apple_versioning.c?txt) open source apple c file.  Notice the second `extern const char` declaration, pretty spooky, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ld$add$osXX.X$SYMBOL` is a linker directive that allows one to redirect symbol resolution in a library.  The command sits in the __DATA section of a binary and is parsed by `ld` at link time to change the visibility of exported symbols.  The linker on OS X actually accepts quite a few different kinds of these commands:

`$ld$hide$osXX.X$SYMBOL` Adds that symbol to the ignore set.  The Linker will no longer export that symbol to any binaries that link with the library even though it may have global visibility.

`$ld$add$osXX.X$SYMBOL` Adds that symbol to the binary at link time regardless of whether a definition exists.

`$ld$install_name$osXX.X` Redirects the definition of a symbol in a particular binary to another binary.  This is used to work around an issue in OS X where CoreGraphics used to exist as a sub-framework of ApplicationServices.  All symbols are now redirected around to the proper framework.

`$ld$compatibility_version` Forces compatibility with earlier versions of the Linker.

In your case, you've bumped up against a compatibility issue in Foundation.  OS X exported NSFileWrapper in AppKit until 10.7 when the symbol was hidden from there and moved to Foundation.  Normally, this means the author of AppKit would hide the _OBJC_CLASS_$, _OBJC_METACLASS_$, and _OBJC_IVAR_$ parts of a class definition to make the linker look elsewhere for that symbol.  However, because you removed the `-fobjc-abi-version` flag the compiler defaults back to the old 1.x ABI which only requires the hiding and finding of a `.objc_class_name` which probably don't exist in the binary you're trying to link.

As for your undefined symbols, it's a simple file extension issue.  .cpp are c++ ***only*** files, (which means no NSRunloop, MSMutableArray, NSObject, etc).  If you wish to access these objects, rename the offending files with the extension .mm, which is a standard objC++ file.  It's also a good idea to link against and import QuartzCore (for EAGL2View) and UIKit (for UIScreen and friends along with UIAccelerometer).

Comment: I built a new application where the main class is a .mm and I'm still getting these errors. Could this be a problem with using llvm-gcc instead of clang?

Comment: Awarding points for a good answer... though I guess the question was pretty dumb now that I know.

Comment: Actually they are not "compiler functions" but metadata for the static linker. See http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-136/src/ld/parsers/macho_dylib_file.cpp , look for "hide"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clued up on the iOS SDK, but why are you compiling for "i386"?.  I ran into this similar problem a few nights ago while playing with PhoneGap.  I just removed "i386" from my XCode project settings and everything seemed to work fine in the simulator after that.  Though i could be wrong.

Comment: I always thought i386 was the sim.  In fact, the build settings for all of my projects have it as one of the standard archs.