# Linking to libraries with $ld$hide$os10.X$ symbols in OSX

Tags: macos, linker

I'm trying to link against the BLAS implementation in OSX (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib`, for the curious) but I don't want to link against the `libLAPACK.dylib` in that same directory, as I want to use my own build of LAPACK from netlib, as it is much more recent and up to date.

My problem is that there are symbols in the BLAS library that are typically stored in an LAPACK library, and as such are causing name clashes.  As a concrete example, the `spotrf` function is defined in `libBLAS.dylib`:

```
$ nm /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib | grep spotrf
0000000000010c05 T $ld$hide$os10.7$_spotrf
0000000000010c05 T $ld$hide$os10.8$_spotrf
000000000000746e T _spotrf
```

Those first two symbols made me a little suspicious, so to double-check, I check out `libLAPACK.dylib` as well:

```
$ nm /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib | grep spotrf
00000000000010c8 T $ld$hide$os10.4$_spotrf
00000000000010c8 T $ld$hide$os10.5$_spotrf
00000000000010c8 T $ld$hide$os10.6$_spotrf
000000000000765b T _spotrf
```

From what [limited information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134189/what-does-the-ldaddos10-4-prefix-mean-when-i-use-nm-to-look-at-a-symbol-list) I have been able to find, it seems that this prefix somehow instructs the dynamic linker to ignore these symbols if the users is compiling against a given OSX version.  This makes sense if Apple moved symbols from `libBLAS.dylib` to `libLAPACK.dylib` between 10.6 and 10.7.

My question is, how can I inform the dynamic linker that it SHOULD hide `spotrf` etc... that are inside `libBLAS.dylib`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the name clashes you're experiencing manifest? OS X's use of two level namespacing should allow symbols with identical names to be present in different libraries that are loaded at runtime. The static linker will record at build time in which dynamic library it found a given symbol and the dynamic loader will use that information at runtime to load and resolve it in the appropriate library.

Comment: This is part of the [Julia language](http://julialang,org), we have a JIT compiler that uses LLVM as its backend.  LLVM has some [dynamic library helper functions](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1sys_1_1DynamicLibrary.html), and we check if a symbol exists already in the symbol table before adding them, printing out a warning to the user as this isn't something we ever really want to happen. The conflict is between an external 3rd-party shared library (`liblapack.dylib`), compiled for Julia) and an external OSX-provided shared library (`libBLAS.dylib`)

Comment: I want the dynamic linker to ignore these conflicting symbols inside of `libBLAS.dylib`, as I'm pretty sure they're only supposed to appear in OSX 10.6 and earlier.  I mistyped compiler instead of dynamic linker above, I'll fix that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don’t actually need to do anything special to get your desired behavior, as you’re linking dynamically.  Ensure that your netlib-built LAPACK appears before -lblas in the link command, and all LAPACK interfaces will be picked up from the netlib LAPACK (`ld` matches all the undefined symbols it can against each of the libraries being linked against in order).

Alternatively, assuming that your netlib LAPACK is linked against the system BLAS, you should be able to configure the link of LAPACK so that it reexports all of the BLAS symbols.  Then you can simply link against your LAPACK and leave -lblas out of your link command entirely.

---

The `$show$` and `$hide$` symbols come into play if and only if you are linking against both the system BLAS and the system LAPACK libs.  A simple example will show how they work in that case:

```
Kronecker:~ scanon$ cat foo.c
void dgetrf_(void);
int main(void) { dgetrf_(); return 0; }
```

Building this on 10.9 and breaking on `dgetrf_`, we see that the symbol was picked up from `libLAPACK.dylib`, even though `-lblas` appears first in the build command.  This is because the symbol is *hidden* in `libBLAS.dylib` when targeting 10.9:

```
Kronecker:~ scanon$ clang foo.c -lblas -llapack
Kronecker:~ scanon$ lldb a.out 
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) b dgetrf_
Breakpoint 1: 2 locations.
(lldb) run
...
frame #0: 0x00007fff89237b70 libLAPACK.dylib`dgetrf
libLAPACK.dylib`dgetrf:
...
```

If we specify `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` (telling the compiler and linker that we want to produce an executable that can run on 10.6 Snow Leopard), we will see that the symbol is picked up from `libBLAS.dylib` instead.  This is because the symbol doesn’t exist in `libLAPACK.dylib` on 10.6, so our executable wouldn’t be able to run on that platform if the symbol in `libLAPACK.dylib` were used:

```
Kronecker:~ scanon$ clang foo.c -lblas -llapack -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
Kronecker:~ scanon$ lldb a.out 
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) b dgetrf_
Breakpoint 1: 2 locations.
(lldb) run
...
frame #0: 0x00007fff8c9d6841 libBLAS.dylib`DGETRF_
libBLAS.dylib`DGETRF_:
...
```

Comment: For those of you that try this with `gcc` and notice that it still doesn't work, ensure that you pass the `macosx-version` flag to both the compiler and the linker parts of `gcc`: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wl,-macosx_version_min,10.6`.  Great answer, thanks!